# Cannot remove listener on Hot Module Replacement

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-hmr

I am registering a handler (for click event). Before registering the handler, I clear the same handler so as not to register two same handlers.

I am using Webpack's Hot Module Replacement. Every time I change something in the JavaScript source code, part of code registering the handler is rerun.

However, the handler is never removed.

```
export default class TaskHandlers {
    // Called from index.js
    registerAddTaskClick(addTaskElementId) {
        let element = document.querySelector(`#${addTaskElementId}`);
        if (element !== null) {
            // Never clears the handler
            element.removeEventListener('click', this.handleAddTaskClick);
            // Keeps piling on new handlers on every HMR.
            element.addEventListener('click', this.handleAddTaskClick);
        }
    }

    handleAddTaskClick(event) {
        console.log('Clicked');
    }
}
```

If I run `element.removeEventListener()` manually, only the last handler gets removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the reference to the function so that you remove the same function you're adding, you'll also need to `.bind(this)`.

```
export default class TaskHandlers {
    constructor() {
        this.element = document.querySelector(`#${addTaskElementId}`);
        this.handleAddTaskClick = this.handleAddTaskClick.bind(this);
    }

    // Called from index.js
    registerAddTaskClick(addTaskElementId) {
        if (this.element !== null) {
            this.element.addEventListener('click', this.handleAddTaskClick);
        }
    }

    handleAddTaskClick(event) {
        this.element.removeEventListener('click', this.handleAddTaskClick);
        console.log('Clicked');
    }
}
```

**Update:** 
Also remove the element when you click it and not before, so that you know that it already has a listener binded.

A solution that *might* work (if it's really needed to keep the instance after changing the code with HMR) is to save the handler in the window object or a global variable that is not part of the module that's refreshed, it's not ideal but might do the trick for you since it's an exceptional case.

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working, new handlers keep getting added. I thought `.bind()` creates a copy of the function and that it is not the same function?

Comment: `.bind()` _binds_ the current scope to the function so that it's maintained. I think I understand now what you want to achieve, but what's happening is that HMR is generating a new instance of your code because it has changed, so that's why it's not removing the previous listener, because the instance is not the same, this will only happen with HMR though, why is it important?

Comment: Should I register event handlers in some other way? Reason for the question: I am playing around with Webpack and HMR and have come across this issue. How would someone who works with HMR in dev environment register his handlers?

Comment: if your previous handler being removed correctly when you click it?

Comment: When I click it? No, nothing is removed. On the contrary, every registered handler gets triggered.

Comment: I'll make an update to the answer and you can try that.

Comment: try the change.

Comment: No effect. The constructor gets rerun as well. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: :\ This should work if you click the listener without doing any changes in the code in the middle, if you really want to keep the instance even after changing the code with HMR, you should save the listener in the window object or a global variable the doesn't get deleted when the module is hot reloaded.

Comment: Yes, saving the handler in the window object does the trick. It does not feel right, but at least it allows me to continue playing with HMR. If you write it up as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, modified the answer to reflect the solution.